# Perform t.test on multiple automatically generated dataframes?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a df of 241 columns and 114 rows. Column 60:241 are numerical values were I would like to perform a paired t test on according to the variable Group (T1 and T2). For an individual variable I managed to do this with the reshape2 package acast command and t.test afterwards, but it would save me a lot of manual work if I could find a command to do this automatically for all the 182 variables.

I tried to make a simplified example of what I want to code:

```
> df
  PatientID Group Immvar1 Immvar2
1         1    T1       4       5
2         2    T1       7       8
3         2    T2       9      10
4         3    T1       2       3
5         3    T2       4       5
6         4    T1       1       2
7         4    T2       9      10

> df1 <- as.data.frame(acast(df$PatientID ~df$Group, data = df, fill=0, value.var=("Immvar1")))
> df1
  T1 T2
1  4  0
2  7  9
3  2  4
4  1  9
> t.test(df1$T1,df1$T2, paired=TRUE)
```

The code I already constructed to make this run automatically looks as follows:

```
df2 <-df[,3:4]
modelList<-list()
for (i in 1:ncol(df2)) {
  matrix <- formula(paste("as.data.frame(acast(PatientID ~ Group , data = df1, fill=0, value.var=(", names(df2[i]),")))"))
  modelList[[i]] <-t.test(matrix$T1, matrix$T2, paired=TRUE)
}
```

But I always get error messages when running this command:

Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'Immvar1' not found

Maybe I have to approach this entirely different and is the modellist/formula combination not suited for this kind of operation. Does anybody have an idea to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your formula/paste line is the problem; you should instead call the cast function directly. (And dcast will put it into a data.frame automatically.) Without a reproducible example, I can't test this, but here's a guess of what that would look like. I also use `lapply` to take care of the bookkeeping.

```
results <- lapply(names(df)[3:4], function(n) {
    matrix <- dcast(PatientID ~ Group, data = df, fill=0, value.var=n)
    t.test(matrix$T1, matrix$T2, paired=TRUE)
})
```

Also, are you sure you want to fill missing lines with zeros? Usually when something is missing the value is unknown.

Other things you might consider to avoid casting first are using the formula notation for t.test (though it requires the paired values to line up, so missing values would be a problem), or using a two-way Anova on Group and PatientID (which is equivalent).

For collecting the results of the tests, you need to gather the pieces you want from the output. Run `str(tmp)` or `unclass(tmp)` to see what the output actually looks like. It's a list, so you can gather the pieces you need either individually using `$` or together using `[` and then unlisting them. To put in a matrix, you need to `rbind` them together, and since the elements you want to rbind are in a list already, you do that using `do.call`. For example

```
tmp <- lapply(results, function(x) unlist(x[c("statistic", "parameter", 
                "p.value", "conf.int", "estimate")]))
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, tmp))
```

Hadley Wickham's various packages provide alternate ways to do this "split-apply-combine"; `melt` from `reshape2` and `ddply` from `plyr` are what I would use if I was to use those packages, but there's nothing wrong with using base R as we've done here.

Comment: Thank you very very much! After some adapting it also worked on my original dataset! Really great and saves me a lot of work! And indeed, you are of course entirely right about the NA vs 0. I don't know if you maybe know a simple way to do it, but is it also possible that R lines up the results of the t.test in a more excelfriendly way? I use tidy and glance for from the package broom when performing linear regressions, but I don't know al alternative for t.test.

Comment: I think you have to replace the unlist(tmp[.. by unlist(x[... in the code and then it works great!! This is a command I can apply to a lot of my other scripts too. Thank you very much again!